# Django registration test script not running

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to write unit a test for a custom registration form on my Django website, but having an error when I run the `python manage.py test`.  I'm trying to run the following test:

```
def test_registration_valid_view(self):
    '''

    '''
    pass
    user_count = User.objects.count()
    form_data = {'username': 'test@example.com',
                 'first_name': 'Test',
                 'last_name': 'Person',
                 'password1': 'admin123',
                 'password2': 'admin123'}
    response = self.client.post("/sign-up/",
                                form_data)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(User.objects.count(), user_count+1)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_registration_valid_view (accounts.tests.RegistrationTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/haldunanil/Desktop/cashonly/accounts/tests.py", line 59, in test_registration_valid_view
    form_data)
  File "/Users/haldunanil/anaconda/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 541, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/Users/haldunanil/anaconda/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 343, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/Users/haldunanil/anaconda/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 409, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/Users/haldunanil/anaconda/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 494, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/haldunanil/anaconda/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/haldunanil/anaconda/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/haldunanil/anaconda/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/haldunanil/anaconda/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/haldunanil/Desktop/cashonly/accounts/decorators.py", line 27, in wrap
    return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haldunanil/Desktop/cashonly/accounts/views.py", line 16, in registration
    form.save()
  File "/Users/haldunanil/Desktop/cashonly/accounts/forms.py", line 32, in save
    group = Group.objects.get(name='Consumers')
  File "/Users/haldunanil/anaconda/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haldunanil/anaconda/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 385, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Not sure what the issue is here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is not related to this test case. Django is failing in this line:

`Group.objects.get(name='Consumers')`

You don't have any group with name 'Consumers'. Remember that Django sets up a fresh database for the unit tests, so you must populate the test database prior to run the test cases.

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that!